# name for a function that composes additively

Tags: functions

Suppose that the function $T: \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathcal{X}$ has the property that $T(T(x, z_1), z_2) = T(x, z_1 + z_2)$.  For example, rotations and translations have this property -- if I rotate 40 degrees and then rotate the result 30 degrees, this is equivalent to rotating by 70 degrees.

What is such a function called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $T$ satisfying this property is closely related to an [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of the additive group of $\mathbb{R}^k$ on $\mathcal{X}$.  If we also add the natural condition that $T(x, 0) = x$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$, then the two are in fact equivalent.  Namely, given such a function $T$, we can define an action such that $v \cdot x := T(x, v)$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a name for the special case of the group action of $G$ on $\mathcal{X}$ where $G$ is the additive group of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If $T(x, \cdot)$ is a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $x$, you might call it a representation of $G$ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory .  Otherwise, not really that I know of.